# Add cloned element to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know that in order to be able to add "duplicates" in an `ng-repeat` you use `track by`, but this is not working in my case

I have the following ng-repeat directive:

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="surveyData in surveyDatas track by $index">
```

My user might want to add a new SurveyData to that list, and the difference between them might be just one field out of 50, so cloning it would be the ideal solution, so I try to go about it like this:

DOM:

```
<button class="btn-sm btn-danger margin10" ng-click="cloneSurveyData(surveyData)">Clone Survey Data:</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.cloneSurveyData = function (surveyData){
     surveyData.id = null;
     $scope.surveyDatas.push(surveyData);
};
```

But, of course, I get:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: surveyData in surveyDatas | orderBy:'id', Duplicate key: object:150
```

I've tried tracking by id, and creating a variable in the controller and then equalling it to the SurveyData, nothing

Is my only option to create a new variable and equalize all fields?

Comment: try to copy the surveyData with angular.copy to a tmp variable and then push it to the array

Comment: You, sir, are my personal hero today, it worked fine, please post answer so I can upvote and accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to copy the surveyData with angular.copy to a tmp variable and then push it to the array:

```
$scope.cloneSurveyData = function (surveyData){
    var temp = angular.copy(surveyData);
    temp.id = null;
    $scope.surveyDatas.push(temp);
};
```

**Edit:**

As explanation i hope this will help:

You didn't have a `order by` inside your example code but you had it in the error  text:

> Repeater: surveyData in surveyDatas | orderBy:'id', Duplicate key: object:150

With your code you only created a reference and pushed it to the array. So the `orderBy` tried to order two objects with exactly the same object id.

Comment: The order by was there in one of the trials I made, I tried with and without order in combination with track by, I just copy-pasted the latest error, my bad

Comment: Then i guess it will be the same in the "track by"